# How to delete specific row in tableview cell when tapping button in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibutton

I want to delete specific row when i tap a button in that cell. but here rows are deleting on the index base. if i tap button in fifth row button but 0th index row is deleting.

please help me.

here is my code:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! EmployeeTableViewCell
    //cell.empImage.image = UIImage(named: countryArray[indexPath.row])
    cell.empName.text = namesArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.cellExpendButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.cellExpendButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(expandcollapseButtonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.removeRowButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(removerowButtonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell
} 

@objc func removerowButtonClicked(sender : UIButton!) {
    namesArray.remove(at: sender.tag)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

I want to remove cell in which button i tapped.

Comment: set `cell.removeRowButton.tag = indexPath.row`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `removeRowButton.tag` by `indexPath.row`, now you are setting `cell.cellExpendButton.tag = indexPath.row`, by default tag of any component is `0`

```
cell.removeRowButton.tag = indexPath.row
```

Comment: Please note that this solution can fail if the rows of the table view can be deleted, inserted, or moved. It's best to avoid tags and determine the indexPath based on the location of the button in the view.

Comment: can u please answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56208548/how-to-select-deselect-tableview-row-in-swift